# Django third party library url pattern before custom url pattern? (url pattern order)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

Using Django (REST Framework) this is my root url conf :

```
... (imports)

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"^confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$", accounts_views.email_verification,
            name="account_confirm_email"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('request/', include('request.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/', TemplateView.as_view(),
            name='account_email_verification_sent'),
]
```

now, I am using the **django-rest-auth** library for authentication. This library sends a email to the user after they submit the registration form, for the purpose of activating the user's email address.

In this email is a link, which is obtained by reversing an url pattern, the url pattern named: **account_confirm_email**

the django-rest-auth library comes with it's own url pattern named **account_confirm_email**, in the following file, to be precise:

python3.7/site-packages/rest_auth/registration/urls.py:

```
... (imports)

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', TemplateView.as_view(),
        name='account_confirm_email'),
]
```

**I expect my own url pattern to be the one that is reversed**, not the rest-auth one, since mine comes first in order. As the Django docs state:

> Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first
>   one that matches the requested URL.

*https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/*

**But in practice the rest-auth pattern is the one that is being reversed, why does this happen?**

To be complete, I see that the Django docs also say:

> Django determines the root URLconf module to use. Ordinarily, this is
>   the value of the ROOT_URLCONF setting, but if the incoming HttpRequest
>   object has a urlconf attribute (set by middleware), its value will be
>   used in place of the ROOT_URLCONF setting.

*https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/*

Does django-rest-auth do what is being described in the above quote of the Django docs? And if so, is it still possible to have my own url pattern be reversed before django-rest-auth's pattern? (And how would I do that?)

Comment: Your quotes from the docs don't actually apply to the same situation you have here - they're talking about what happens when a request is made to a concrete URL and Django looks up which view function to call, which isn't necessarily the same as the order it checks for a reverse match (finding the URL based on a name it's given). I've just checked the docs and so far haven't found any information on what order this goes in - logically it would be the same, but perhaps it's not? Would be nice to find out one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

*It is expected to behave that way*, because the URLPattern that you wrote will not match the URL present in the email sent through **django-rest-auth** library.

Replace this line:

```
re_path(r"^confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$", accounts_views.email_verification, name="account_confirm_email"),
```

For this:

```
re_path(r"^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$", accounts_views.email_verification, name="account_confirm_email"),
```

Comment: I downvoted because I am talking about the url pattern named account_confirm_email, which I do already have added to my own root url conf file, with regex included. The url pattern you talk about it at the bottom of my list, mine is at the top.

Comment: @RikSchoonbeek Correct me again if I am mistaken but I find it normal that the one you are referring about is not being entered in the email URL, as long as it follows a different regex, even though it has the same name.

Comment: The url pattern being reversed is the one named "account_confirm_email". The other `re_path` pattern is named differently, namely "account_email_verification_sent", and it is not really related to this question. I hope you don't take my downvote personally, but I didn't really like that the answer already had two upvotes while it doesn't answer my question. Do appreciate your effort!

Comment: @RikSchoonbeek I changed my answer, it may be adapted now to what you need. If not, I would kindly ask you for more details on the core problem you want to solve.
PD: It is nice to always have a discussion over a non solved matter, thanks for your comments!